# Apple Mail and using Rule to save pdf from url in message

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Environment: Mac
Application: Apple Mail

I receive several mails/day that contains an url to a PDF that i would like to save automatically using a Rule,  to a specific folder.

I did manage to create a Service in Automator that actually saves the pdf from any choosen mail, but cannot automate this using a Rule. :-(

I've tried several Applescripts but at no success...

So, after 4 days of Google i give up, can anyone help me?

Sincerely/
Erik

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Service that will do the work, you can write an AppleScript that will call the Service using the automator command line utility. See [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95450/how-do-i-invoke-a-service-using-applescript) for details. Then you can point the Rule at the AppleScript and away you go.